# UIView with UITableView as subview

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIView with a UITableView as subview. When I add a gesture recogniser to the view, my "table did select row" is not triggered anymore, but the gesture recogniser is always triggered? I have tried to remove the gesture recogniser from the tableview, but it has no effect.

```
let viewRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap")
viewRecognizer.delegate = self
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(viewRecognizer)
//This has no effect!
orderTableView.removeGestureRecognizer(viewRecognizer)
```

Comment: When a touch is detected, it goes to each view from the top of the stack to the bottom until it hits a view that can handle it, then does not continue to the rest. Your view is detecting the touch and so it is never forwarded to the tableview.

Comment: OK, so I have to use the locationInView and the indexPathForRowAtPoint I suppose. Just seems a dirty way to do it?

Comment: Why do you need a gestureRecognizer on the area that the tableview occupies? Could you make a second subview for the area not occupied by the tableView and then set a gestureRecognizer on that?

Comment: I dont. But I need one on the area that surrounds it! I need it on the view, but not on the tableview subview. When I add it to the surrounding view, it also works in the table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the `cancelsTouchesInView` to `NO` for the `UIView`?

See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/cancelsTouchesInView)

Comment: Hi I ended up doing like this:  let location = recognizer.locationInView(self.orderTableView)
        if let indexPath = self.orderTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location){...do you stuff....}